# How do I restore libraries in iTunes using files on my iPod Touch?

Tags: windows-xp, itunes, ipod-touch

I have iTunes (latest version) running on Windows XP and a 16Gb 1st gen' iPod Touch (iOS V3.1.3). All was well until a month or two ago when, one day, I opened iTunes to discover it was empty - no music library, videos, apps etc. It was as if it was a fresh install. So, all my files are on my Touch but I've avoided connecting it to iTunes for fear all my files will disappear.

I can't put it off much longer so my question is, **what do I have to do in iTunes so it restores its libraries from the files on my iPod Touch (without messing with the files on my Touch)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to achieve something similar recently and the only way I have found is to use a commercial product called [pod to pc](http://www.macroplant.com/podtopc/).

Comment: After looking for a free alternative, I eventually did it with Pod to PC. Thanks for the tip reg.

Answer (score 0):

Use a music recovery software like [Senuti](http://www.fadingred.com/senuti/). The trial version allows you to recover 1000 songs from your iPod. So if you don't pass the limit then this solution is free. Otherwise you need to buy it.

The company that makes Senuti claims that their product "recover all your music, playlists, and videos to iTunes in one step."

Tried it before for a friend and it works like they claim.