# How do I download tunes from an iPod back onto iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipod, reinstall

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Transferring Music from iPod to iTunes?](https://superuser.com/questions/15420/transferring-music-from-ipod-to-itunes)
>   [How do I restore libraries in iTunes using files on my iPod Touch?](https://superuser.com/questions/177288/how-do-i-restore-libraries-in-itunes-using-files-on-my-ipod-touch)

I recently lost all my data on my HD and backup (!!!) including my songs held on iTunes.  The tracks are still on my iPod (nano) but if I reinstall iTunes and sync it with my iPod it will wipe my iPod.  Obviously I don't want to have to reload all those CD's back onto my computer, so how do I download the tracks from my iPod?
I did find a piece of software called MediaWidget but only allows 10 tracks at a time or option to pay for full access.  I did try 10 track version but that had a problem syncing it back on to iTunes, so don't want to pay for full version because that may not work either.
Any help would be appreciated
Many Thanks

Comment: Look at [Transferring Music from iPod to iTunes?](http://superuser.com/questions/15420/transferring-music-from-ipod-to-itunes)

Answer (score 0):

I asked a [near identical question](https://superuser.com/questions/177288/how-do-i-restore-libraries-in-itunes-using-files-on-my-ipod-touch) and got a couple of answers. Haven't got round to trying them yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/)? You can copy all the files from the ipod to the computer and then import them into itunes. Next: Sync.

Comment: Thanks to Andygrunt, Andi and NX Wolf for your suggestions.  However I have resolved the problem via PodtoPC, did try MediaWidget but that wouldn't work at the final execution.  PodtoPC has the freebie element of 10 songs at a time, which is a hassle but it allowed me to prove the s/w worked. So spent the $19 and it worked a dream! Seems ridiculous that Apple don't have this feature within iTunes or any sign of Help within their site.  Thanks again for taking the time to respond - Appreciate it.